# how to control accessible search engines?

Tags: seo, meta-tags

I have been asked that if it is possible to restrict search results in search engines.. here is an example: I have a website and I want it to be shown only in yahoo, google, bing and ask search engines.. is there any way to do it by using any of the meta tags or by another way?

thanks..

Answer (score 0):

robots.txt? I think that is what you can use to restrict Search engines. http://www.robotstxt.org/

Answer (score 0):

You can Control the Accessible search engine by two methods are as follow:
1. Robots Meta tags
2. Robots.txt file

Robots Meta Tags: 

this tags means to tell web crawler following page does not index or show in search results in search engine.

Robots.txt file:
this is a text file submitted to webmaster tool.
eg: user agent: *
    disallow: /

This code means all search spider except yahoo this website does not index in search engine.